# Vim netrw shows dot file/directory even when set to be hidden

Tags: vim, netrw

So the following is my netrw configuration:

```
let g:netrw_winsize=-35
let g:netrw_localrmdir='rm -r'
let g:netrw_fastbrowse=0
let g:netrw_hide=0
let g:netrw_list_hide= '*/\.git,*/\.DS_Store$'let g:netrw_sizestyle="h"
let g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

When opening netrw (e.g. `:Explore`) I find both the `.git` directory and the `.DS_Store` file are still visible when I'd expect them *not* to be visible.

At first I thought it might be the `netrw_hide=0` which is to show ALL files (even though I'd expect `netrw_list_hide` to override that). But I removed that setting and the problem persisted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The config setting applies to *filenames*, not the entire file path + name. So, you need to drop the leading `*/`, and instead anchor with `^`:

```
let g:netrw_list_hide= '^\.git$,^\.DS_Store$'
let g:netrw_sizestyle="h"
```

Also, the second config needs to be on a separate line, but I guess that was a simple typo in your question.

Comment: Hi Ingo, that's for the response. I tried that like so: `let g:netrw_list_hide= '^\.git,^\.DS_Store$'` but it still didn't work :-(